# What Layout is best to set its inner views based on coordinates

Tags: android, android-layout

Which layout supports setting its inner / contained views based on (x, y) coordinates, I looked into AbsoluteLayout but I found that it's deprecated since API 3 ... I know the reason behind AbsoluteLayout deprecation, but in my case it's not a problem and it's required.

> Absolute layout are harder to maintain for different mobile screen
>   sizes than other types of layouts because we set the exact location of
>   a child view or called component. The positioning is based on x(top)
>   and y(left) coordinates and that positioning is not as useful in world
>   of various screen resolutions(sizes) and aspect ratios.

P.S: If my only choice is RelativeLayout or FrameLayout (by updating child margins), knowing that the user controls the position of the child / contained view by pressing it and repositioning it, how to do that in most efficient way?

Comment: You could also use `CoordinatorLayout` with `setTranslationX` or `setTranslationY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you go with `FrameLayout` and animate the child views base on touch coordinate, don't touch the view's margins.

The easiest approach is to use the built-in `ViewPropertyAnimator` of `View` by calling `animate()`. You can translate the view by calling:

```
view.animate().translateX(xCoord).translateY(yCoord).setDuration(0).start()
```

on every touch movement.

There will be some unsmooth movement when the coordinate is changed too fast. Check this library for smooth animation on touch: https://github.com/wirecube/android_additive_animations